# Problems Crawling a Community Site

Tags: community

My office recently moved our knowledgebase to a Salesforce community site. I've been asked to crawl the community to find broken links after the migration.

This has more or less stumped a number of crawling tools that I've used including Xenu and Screaming Frog. They all are having issues with the heavy use of Javascript to place all/most content on the page. Screaming Frog mostly just gets back blank pages even when set to handle Javascript.

For instance, using https://community.logitech.com/s/ as an example, if you disable JS nothing loads.

I haven't worked with Salesforce products much. Has anyone been able to successfully crawl their community pages? Any ways of successfully doing this?

Comment: Did you include a robots.txt in your community? I think there's something in the documentation about this.

Comment: @crmprogdev Yep, there's a robots.txt file but it hasn't been configured to restrict anything. Currently it only points to the sitemap.